# kerberos: Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC

Tags: java, spring-security, kerberos, spnego

I can not run the Spring security Kerberos example. I have this error:

> GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level:
>   Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to
>   decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC)

Application server: Centos 6, Glassfish V3

DC: Windows 2008 R2 server

Customer: Windows 7

Comment: Can you provide more details ? (such as Spring ,kerberos version, jre version etc)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which versions you are on. I was getting exactly the same error on Kerberos version 1.0.0.M1 over JRE 7 initial version. Update JRE to the latest and update Kerberos to 1.0.0.RELEASE resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because the keytab file was generated with the wrong `/crypto` configuration.
 Generate a new keytab file using `/crypto ALL` with the `ktpass` command:

```
ktpass /out "server.keytab" /crypto ALL /princ HTTP/server@REALM /mapuser KERBEROS_SERVICEUSER /pass PASSWORD /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
```

Replace `HTTP/server@REALM`, `KERBEROS_SERVICEUSER` and `PASSWORD` with according values.